# ExcelJS - Freezing rows other than the first

Tags: javascript, excel, rows, exceljs

I've been trying to freeze row A9 but whatever I do, it seems like freezing rows only works starting from the first row.
Is there a way to freeze a single row that is not the first?

[Official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs) doesn't show any information on this issue and changing the variables, trying to select any other row to freeze while it has unfrozen rows on top of it doesn't work.

```
ws.views = [
  {state: 'frozen', xSplit: , ySplit: 3, topLeftCell: 'A7'}
];
```

Could it be a limitation by Excel itself or the ExcelJS library?

**Answer: For others looking for solution, it seems it is something that Excel itself doesn't support, not ExcelJS.**

Comment: @BigBen The question is, what code do I need. I can put a general code in there but that makes zero sense.

Comment: @BigBen Alright, I'll paste the code from the official documentation.